# Does -Xmx stop automatic GC till maximum memory is consumed?

Tags: java

My question is simple. I have an application that specifies the "-Xmx 3G" command line option. Does this mean that no garbage collection will take place in the application till all (or say 80%) the 3GB of memory is consumed? Any further reading material would be appreciated as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java garbage collector - When does it collect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582209/java-garbage-collector-when-does-it-collect)

Comment: Any specific reason why you'd want to avoid GC completely?

Comment: on startup. I can understand avoiding it for a running system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A minor gc can occur even before the minimum memory -ms has been reached.  The JVm reserves the maximum memory -mx on startup. However you can get full collections before this size is reached.

Answer (score 1):

No. A simple test would demonstrate that!